# Date difference calculation between now and date from SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'd like to calculate date difference between Now and date from SQL Server using with .NET.

My aim is creating condition to provide or prevent update SQL rows. For example if datediff between NOW and InsertDate(date when data was first entered into the SQL Server) <= 2 then update the row else don't.

So, I wrote code but it doesn't work and returns with this error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'.

I'm sharing this code with you and I hope you'll help me.

```
Dim oku As SqlDataReader

Dim datelimit As Long = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, DateTime.Now, oku.GetDateTime("InsertDate where QR = '" & qrcode.Text & "'"))

If datelimit <= 2 then

dim sql as string = "Update Table set ...."
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to filter on the date differences in the SQL. A pseudo example is below.

```
Dim oku As SqlDataReader

Dim datelimit As Long = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, DateTime.Now, 
oku.GetDateTime("InsertDate where QR = '" & qrcode.Text & "'"))

dim sql as string = "Update Table set ....where QR = '" & qrcode.Text & "'" and (DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), InsertDate)) > 1"
```

If the "insertdate" value comes from another table then you can use join syntax on the update statement. If the "insertdate" value is held somewhere in code (although it looks like you're retrieving it from a query object) then you can either inject it into the SQL statement directly, as you are with the qrcode.Text, or you can add it as a parameter to the query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I understood with this way I don't need to use "datelimit" statement which I've defined "as long" anymore.

Comment: That's right, which means that you shouldn't get an error for that parameter being null because you don't need to worry about setting the insertdate value there via the SqlDataReader component.

Comment: I have another question about that. I'd like to display errors when one of these conditions (QR= qrcode.text and DATEDIFF) aren't provided (qrcode.text doesn't exist or datediff > 2) messages of these errors should include cause of the error (exp: for 1st condition : QR Doesn't Exist ! or for 2nd condition: DATEDIFF up to cycle time !)  If I'd put these conditions into the .NET query I'd use TRY-CATCH for every conditions individually. how I can provide that when I implement the update conditions into the SQL query?

Comment: As far as the qrcode.text is concerned, just handle that as you otherwise would. As for datediff > 2, as far as the code is concerned you would just update 0 rows. If you want to show that then perhaps you could use a stored procedure instead of a hardcoded query then add a return value. You could then even test the datediff > 2 condition in the stored procedure and return the result of that if you wanted.